# Display, NOT filter, 3 specific periods in a QuickSight table

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Can anyone confirm if QuickSight has the functionality to display a specified number of columns in a table?

Example: I have a pivot table that displays 12 months of data in the columns, region in rows with counts for the values and aggregate totals.

[Example pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztZAH.jpg)

My aim is to focus on April, May and June. If I filter for those months, the totals only reflect those three months. I want to display only April, May and June but retain the annual totals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a field that is being used for rows or columns in a pivot table, but you can't hide specific values from that field (as you need in this case).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/hiding-pivot-table-columns.html